# Read element from XMLTYPE

Tags: xml, soap, oracle12c

hope someone can help.

Within PLSQL I do a soap call and I receive XML result from SOAP.
I need to retrieve an element-value.

This worked fine on this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <S:Body>
      <ns2:executeObjectResponse xmlns:ns2="http://www.uc4.com/uc4/">
         <runID>1120864</runID>
      </ns2:executeObjectResponse>
   </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

with this code:

```
declare
       v_doc               DBMS_XMLDOM.DOMDocument;
       v_Value             VARCHAR2 (2000);
       v_node              DBMS_XMLDOM.DOMNode;
       v_nodelist          DBMS_XMLDOM.DOMNodelist;
begin
      ...  XML result from soap call catched in CLOB => l_result

v_doc := DBMS_XMLDOM.newdomdocument (l_result);
v_nodelist := DBMS_XMLDOM.getelementsbytagname (v_doc, 'runID');
v_node := DBMS_XMLDOM.getfirstchild (DBMS_XMLDOM.item (v_nodelist, 0));
v_value := DBMS_XMLDOM.getnodevalue (v_node);
DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('value a: ' || v_Value);

value a: 1120864
```

I however do have an issue with the following XML.
I need to retrieve the value for this tag:

```
<name>&amp;RESULT#</name>
```

I tried several things, but just can't find the propper code.

The result from SOAP I catch in a CLOB (l_result).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <S:Body>
      <ns2:getTaskDetailsResponse xmlns:ns2="http://www.uc4.com/uc4/">
         <groups>
            <name>General</name>
            <label>SCRI.ADP.SOAP.TEST (1120864)</label>
            <items>
               <name>Object name</name>
               <value>SCRI.ADP.SOAP.TEST</value>
            </items>
            <items>
               <name>Queue</name>
               <value>CLIENT_QUEUE</value>
            </items>
            <items>
               <name>Version</name>
               <value>6</value>
            </items>
            <items>
               <name>RunID</name>
               <value>1120864</value>
            </items>
            <items>
               <name>Activator</name>
               <value>1115216</value>
            </items>
            <items>
               <name>User</name>
               <value>ADP_SOAP/ADP</value>
            </items>
            <items>
               <name>Activation</name>
               <value>2017-05-24T13:38:44</value>
            </items>
            <items>
               <name>Start</name>
               <value>2017-05-24T13:38:45</value>
            </items>
            <items>
               <name>End</name>
               <value>2017-05-24T13:38:45</value>
            </items>
            <items>
               <name>Runtime</name>
               <value>0:00:00</value>
            </items>
            <items>
               <name>Status</name>
               <value>ENDED_OK - ended normally</value>
            </items>
            <items>
               <name>Return code</name>
               <value>0</value>
            </items>
            <items>
               <name>Event ID</name>
               <value>1120864</value>
            </items>
            <items>
               <name>Enable Rollback</name>
               <value>No</value>
            </items>
         </groups>
         <groups>
            <name>Object variables</name>
            <label>SCRI.ADP.SOAP.TEST (1120864)</label>
            <items>
               <name>&amp;EXT_HOSTNAME#</name>
               <value>sz4183</value>
            </items>
            <items>
               <name>&amp;EXT_SOAP_ID#</name>
               <value>sz4183</value>
            </items>
            <items>
               <name>&amp;EXT_SOAP_WF#</name>
               <value>JOBP.ADP.SOAP_TEST1</value>
            </items>
            <items>
               <name>&amp;RESULT#</name>
               <value>/dev;/u01;/etc/mnttab;/etc/dfs/sharetab;/dev/fd;/export;/rpool;/mnt/ora_dba</value>
            </items>
         </groups>
      </ns2:getTaskDetailsResponse>
   </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

I played around with this, but without success:

```
    declare
       v_doc               DBMS_XMLDOM.DOMDocument;
       v_Value             VARCHAR2 (2000);
       v_node              DBMS_XMLDOM.DOMNode;
       v_nodelist          DBMS_XMLDOM.DOMNodelist;
    begin
      ...  XML result from soap call catched in CLOB => l_result
      v_doc := DBMS_XMLDOM.newdomdocument (l_result);
      v_nodelist := DBMS_XMLDOM.getelementsbytagname (v_doc, '&amp;RESULT#');
      v_node := DBMS_XMLDOM.getfirstchild (DBMS_XMLDOM.item (v_nodelist, 0));
      v_value := DBMS_XMLDOM.getnodevalue (v_node);
       DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('value: ' || v_Value);
   end;
```

All sugestions are welcome.

cheers
Wim

Comment: `&amp;RESULT#` is a node text value, not a node name. What are you actually trying to get? The value of the `name` node you refer to is the string you're looking for, so you already have that.... so you want the matching `value` node for that `name` node?

Comment: Thx Alex,

I'm looking for the value following the element NAME with this value.

See post below.. did some more testing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't try to walk the DOM at all, though I suppose you could iterate over `items` nodes, test the `name` text in each one, and stop when you find the one you're interested in - and then use that `items` node's `value` text.

It's easier to use the built-in XML handling though:

```
declare
    l_result clob := '... your SOAP response ...';
    v_Value VARCHAR2 (2000);
begin
    select xmlquery('//items/name[text()=''&amp;RESULT#'']/../value/text()'
      passing xmltype(l_result)
      returning content).getstringval()
    into v_Value
    from dual;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('value: ' || v_Value);
end;
/

value: /dev;/u01;/etc/mnttab;/etc/dfs/sharetab;/dev/fd;/export;/rpool;/mnt/ora_dba

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

You can [read more about XMLQuery in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e23094/xdb_xquery.htm). In this case the XPath I've used:

```
//items/name[text()=''&amp;RESULT#'']/../value/text()
```

looks for an `items/name` node whose text value is the string you want (in escaped single quotes); then finds it's parent (`items`) node using `..`, then finds the `values` node under *that* `items` node. And gets its text value.

(It might be preferable to give the full path to the `items` nodes, and include all the namespace info, but you can add that in; using `//items` ignores the structure above that).

You can do the same thing with your first example too, incidentally:

```
...
begin
    select xmlquery('//runID/text()'
      passing xmltype(l_result)
      returning content).getstringval()
    into v_Value
    from dual;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('value a: ' || v_Value);
end;
/

value a: 1120864

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: Hi Alex,
didn't know how to start onXML at all, so googled some pieces of code.

Your's however is indeed less and simple. 
Thx for your help.. I will use this one.
Works just fine ;)

Cheers Wim

Answer (score 0):

I found that the code works.

```
dbms_xmldom.freeDocument(v_doc);
      v_doc := DBMS_XMLDOM.newdomdocument (l_result);
      v_nodelist := DBMS_XMLDOM.getelementsbytagname (v_doc, 'name');
      v_node := DBMS_XMLDOM.getfirstchild (DBMS_XMLDOM.item (v_nodelist, 19));
      v_value := DBMS_XMLDOM.getnodevalue (v_node);
       DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('name: ' || v_Value);
       v_nodelist := DBMS_XMLDOM.getelementsbytagname (v_doc, 'value');
      v_node := DBMS_XMLDOM.getfirstchild (DBMS_XMLDOM.item (v_nodelist, 17));
      v_value := DBMS_XMLDOM.getnodevalue (v_node);
       DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('value : ' || v_Value);
```

result is:

```
name: &RESULT#
value : /dev;/u01;/etc/mnttab;/etc/dfs/sharetab;/dev/fd;/export;/rpool;/mnt/ora_dba
```

What I'm still trying to find is how to search for the element &RESULT# and the value belonging to this element.
Now I did count the element (19 for name and 17 for value), just to check the code.

cheers Wim

Comment: This shoudl really have been an edit to your question, not an answer.